# Reload the View from AppDelegate in ios

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, reload

I am having some views in my application ,I start syncing(i.e. network related operations and updates my local variable) when application relaunches i.e. on **applicationDidBecomeActive** 
i want to reload the view which was opened when we pressed home button 
I have tried

> [UIViewController loadView];

but it get's crash some times .

Comment: Have a look at [State Restoration and Preservation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `loadView` directly. It's clearly stated in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW1):

> Discussion
>
> You should never call this method directly. The view controller calls this method when its view property is requested but is currently nil. This method loads or creates a view and assigns it to the view property.

Answer (score -1):

You can add in this view controller class method

```
-(void) viewWillAppear;
```

And in this method write: `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` or your reload code

Also you can in `[UIViewController loadView];` code change `loadView` on `viewDidLoad` like this: `[UIViewController viewDidLoad];` when UIViewController is variable of your UIViewController class